# Bundle Identifier

Tags: iphone, bundle, transfer, identifier

I'm running a small team of iPhone developers and am a bit concerned about the application transfers into iPhone from Xcode.

The problem is that whenever an app is transfered into the iphone the earlier transfered app is mysteriously replaced.

My question is, "How do I ensure that every app takes its own respective place and does not replace one another".

I had suggested the whole team to change the name of the bundle identifier in the info.plist to prevent such an event.

Please suggest if there's any other way to ensure that the app is not replaced as it is getting really time consuming for me to transfer the deleted app again and again and it gets expensive in the case of paid apps.

Cheers,

Comment: what do you mean by 'the earlier transferred app'? are you just installing a new build of the same app? Or are you installing several different apps with the same bundle id?? (If so, this is incorrect).

Not sure how paid apps enters into it either - are these apps you build yourself or what?

Comment: see i got it now... when u transfer thru itunes and use a different mac altogether (as we do) the apps that are there in that mac replace the apps if sync all apps option is selected.
the solution will be that we select the particular app while performing the sync instead of selecting all. also if there are some paid apps.. we can keep the .ipa files in different computers.
cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the paid apps, you should be able to manage this through iTunes without downloading or buying again. For example, I've developed an application for my iPhone. I removed it off the device when 1.0 was released and downloaded it using a promo code. When I was coding/testing version 1.1 I would push it onto the phone through Xcode, essentially 'stepping' on the paid app. Whenever I wanted to go back to the 1.0-officially-downloaded-version, I would uncheck the app in iTunes, sync, then recheck. I could also have removed the dev version through XCode organizer and then used iTunes to put the purchased app back on.

Hope that makes sense.